# Get data from JSON using SwifyJson

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to get a data from a JSON using a SwiftyJson framework, the json is just that:

```
{
  "errors" : {
    "email" : [
      "O campo e-mail não contém um endereço de email válido."
    ]
  }
}
```

Using this code:

```
var jsonObject = JSON (json)
jsonObject["errors"]["email"].string!
```

But it come empty

Thanks in advance

Comment: `jsonObject["errors"]["email"]` is an Array, not a String. So `jsonObject["errors"]["email"][0].string`?

Comment: Use codable https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6NEUpLhpUM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value for key `email` is actually array of `String`, so if you need to get element from array, you have to specify index (`array[index]`)

Use this:

```
var jsonObject = JSON (json)
jsonObject["errors"]["email"][0].string!
```

or safer solution:

```
if let string = jsonObject["errors"]["email"][0].string {
    ...
}
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can get value of object with

```
var jsonObject = JSON (json)
jsonObject["errors"]["email"][0].string!
```

`jsonObject["errors"]["email"]` get array value and you want to get object of the array so `jsonObject["errors"]["email"][0]` you get string object so you can write `jsonObject["errors"]["email"][0].string!` and then you get value of string like here...

> "O campo e-mail não contém um endereço de email válido."